# How to remove matched value in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, unset

I am looping thru two Arrays. `$wooProducts` and `$data`. Both arrays look the same and contain WooCommerce products.

My goal is to loop thru `$wooProducts` and remove the matched product from `$data`.
Everything work except the `unset()` part. Any idea how I can make it work? I tried this as well: `unset($data[$matchedProduct]);`

```
// Find function
function find($array, $key) {
    foreach ($array as $product) {
        if ($product["Name"] == $key) {
            return $product;
        }
    }
}

$updateProducts = [];
// Check if product already exist
foreach ($wooProducts as $wooProduct) {
    $matchedProduct = find($data, $wooProduct->post_title);
    if ($matchedProduct) {
        array_push($updateProducts, $matchedProduct);
        unset($data[$wooProduct]); // <---- Not working
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont really know php but when you do a foreach $wooProducts as $wooProduct the variable $wooProduct might be a value rather than an index.  

if my array was $wooProcuts ['cat', 'dog']
My guess is that unset(data[wooProcuct]) is like saying unset(data['cat']) when really you want unset(data[0])

Comment: You try to unset with value, need to unset with key, also wooProduct is object. Object cannot be key in array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_search()` to find the index and then you can use unset.

```
array_search($wooProduct->post_title, $data);
```